# Parse and Tree as much of the input as possible?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm looking to get antlr to parse/tree as much of the input as possible so that the information can be used for intellisense. Maybe this is the wrong approach but seems like the only way to get decent information when the input is not 100% valid.

The grammar has statements which are separated by semicolons. What I want specifically is for antlr to try and parse/tree everything delimited by semicolons. Meaning 1 broken statement shouldn't prevent other statements from being parsed.

I was able to add this to the parser grammar easily using the following.

```
statements
    :   (statement (a=semicolon statement)*  b=semicolon?) -> ^(BLOCK statement ($a statement)* $b?)
    ;
semicolon //Consume invalid tokens until we find a SEMICOLON.
    :   { while(input.LA(1) != EOF && input.LA(1) != SEMICOLON) input.Consume(); } SEMICOLON
    ;
```

That works fine. Here is what I tried for the tree rewrite which the consuming doesn't work.

```
block returns [Statement block = null]
@init{  var statements = new List<Statement>(); }
    :   ^(t=BLOCK (s=statement { statements.Add(s); }) (semicolon s=statement { statements.Add(s); }))* semicolon?) { block = new Statement(li(t), statements); }
    ;
semicolon
    :   { while(input.LA(1) != EOF && input.LA(1) != SEMICOLON) input.Consume(); } SEMICOLON
    ;
```

Looking at the compiled code shows that it looks for a semicolon before consuming. Which won't work because there are invalid tokens before the semicolon.

Here is how I am currently handling parser rule errors.

```
rule : (A B c) => A^ B c
     | A B { c(); } //Calling c reports the error without throwing an exception.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, there are 3 ways to get accurate information from ANTLR for use in code completion and other IDE features. Disclaimer: I am the author of all the items below.

1. (ANTLR 3/4) Rewrite your grammar to be LL(1).
2. (ANTLR 3/4) Rewrite your grammar to be mostly LL(1), then hand-write the error recovery code to derive useful information for every remaining non-LL(1) decision.

   - This method is used for IntelliSense in [Pixel Mine Games' nFringe UnrealScript IDE](http://pixelminegames.com/nfringe/).
3. (ANTLR 4 only) Write a modified ANTLR runtime that operates as a generalized parser allowing and preserving ambiguity.

   - This method is used for [Tunnel Vision Labs' GoWorks](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/products/demo/goworks) code completion and other features (page includes a video of the code completion features starting at 5:01).
4. (Non-ANTLR) Prior to the existence of ANTLR 4, I also wrote a custom parser based on NFA simulation for use in the latest [ANTLR 3 extension for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f). This method doesn't work as well as option 3 so I plan on replacing it eventually.

For my ongoing IDE work, I only use option 3 at this point. Option 2 provided acceptable support prior to the existence of option 3 (GoWorks didn't exist for comparison, so when nFringe was created it was generally viewed as exceptional).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I can't really find any examples of what LL(1) looks like in antlr. I was wondering if you could provide an example. I think I understand it but I would like to just make sure. Also I updated the question showing how I am currently handling errors. I was wondering if that method is fine or if I should be doing something else.